# Render trivial nested boxes

Tags: boxes, stack

I just need nested boxes in latex. Like this:

[image]

with the following constraints:

- the outermost box (black) will **never** be larger than \textwidth or pagewidth
- there is **never** more than one box in a row

I've already tried all kinds of fboxes, makeboxes, colorboxes, stacks etc.
[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133270/nested-boxes-of-different-thickness) comes close, but it still has the problem with several boxes in a row.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
  {\fboxrule=.75pt%
   \fbox{\stackunder{Box 1 }
   {
    \fbox{\stackunder{ Box 2 }{
        \fbox{\stackunder{ Box 4 }{}}  
    }}      
    \fbox{\stackunder{ Box 3 }{}}
   }
  }
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get box 3 under box 2 and limit the entire width to the pagesize?

Comment: please add a MWE for your problem.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added another `\stackunder` with the box2/4 as the first argument, and the box3 as the 2nd.

I also left-aligned the stacks (by default).

However, note that an `\fbox` approach will not limit the eventual overall width, unless you make the content of the `\fbox` to be, for example, a `\parbox` of specified width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
  {\fboxrule=.75pt%
   \fbox{\stackunder{Box 1 }
   {
    \stackunder{%
    \fbox{\stackunder{ Box 2 }{
        \fbox{\stackunder{ Box 4 }{}}  
    }}  
    }{%   
    \fbox{\stackunder{ Box 3 }{}}%
    }
   }
  }
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]